# POSTGRES - psql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "root"

Tags: linux, backup, configuration, postgresql, database

I am trying to configure peer authentication for root on Postgres v9.5. My aim is to allow the cron jobs to run pgdump to create backups.

My pg_hba.conf file looks as follows:

```
local   all             postgres                      md5
local   all             root                          peer  map=mymap
```

My pg_ident.conf file looks like below:

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME

mymap           root                        dbadmin
```

The error when running psql to test as root user is:

> psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "root"

I have seen things like this on here, but they suggest the settings I am already trying, but it doesn't work. Is anyone able to help or advise on a different solution?

I have tried creating a 'backup' user with the commands below on postgres:

```
CREATE ROLE backup WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'backuppasswd';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb To backup;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO backup;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO backup;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO backup;
```

I then have run below:

```
export PGPASSWORD="backuppasswd"
```

I have then created a crontask with the entry below:

```
14 11 * * * pg_dump -U backup -h localhost mydb > /<mypath>
```

If I run "`pg_dump -U backup -h localhost mydb > /<mypath>"` from the command line then it creates the backup, but if I let the cron job run then it creates an empty file.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

You're not trying to connect as `root` but as `dbadmin`. Your entry in `pg_hba.conf` should look like this:

`local   all             dbadmin                          peer  map=mymap`

then you need to run psql with the user aswell:
`# psql -U dbadmin`

Comment: When it's that way round I get the error "psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
"

Comment: It works for me when using these exact entries. Do you have other entries in `pg_hba.conf` before the ones you have posted? Postgres will only check the first entry that matches the connection so if there's a different entry that does not allow you to connect it will stop there and deny access.

Comment: It has the line "local   all             postgres                      peer", before.

Comment: Hm, that line is supposed to be there. I'm out of ideas then, sorry.

Comment: I have tried something new, but still can't get it to work. I have added to my original post, can anyone help?